# JavaScript array: is there a method that is a cross between splice and filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of objects, and want to:

1. Remove certain objects from the array
2. Treat the removed objects in a second step

I don't know in advance where these objects are. To recognize them, I need to use a function that queries their properties. It makes sense to retrieve the removed objects in a second array.

I had hoped to find a native method like `filter` or `splice` that would do this. Here's what I've come up with as a solution:

```
if (!Array.prototype.cherrypick) {
  Array.prototype.cherrypick = function(fn) {
    let basket = []
    let ii = this.length
    let item

    for ( ; ii-- ; ) {
      item = this[ii]

      if (fn(item)) {
        basket.unshift(item)
        this.splice(ii, 1)
      }
    }

    return basket
  }
}
```

Have I missed something? Is there a native method that does this already? Is my solution unsound in some way?

Comment: So you want reduce() ?

Comment: @epascarello, that is too easy ...

Answer (score 1):

Methods such as [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) returns a new array instead of changing the original array.

You can create a partition method using `Array.reduce()` that will return two arrays - those that passed the predicate, and those that failed:

```js
const partition = (predicate, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    r[+!!predicate(o)].push(o);
    
    return r;
  }, [[], []]);
  
const arr = [4, 8, 3, 10, 12];

const result = partition(n => n > 5, arr);

console.log(result);
```

And you can use the partition logic with `Array.splice()` to create the `cherrypick` method:

```js
if (!Array.prototype.cherrypick) {
  Array.prototype.cherrypick = function(predicate) {
    const [removedItems, items] = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
      r[+!!predicate(o)].push(o);

      return r;
    }, [[], []]);
    
    this.splice(0, arr.length, items);
    
    return removedItems;
  }
}

const arr = [4, 8, 3, 10, 12];

const removed = arr.cherrypick(n => n > 5);

console.log('arr ', arr);

console.log('removed ', removed);
```

Comment: `r[+fn(o)]` - nice trick! I would recommend `r[+!!fn(o)]` though

Comment: OP probably wants `([picked, array] = partition(array, fn));`

Answer (score 1):

> Have I missed something? Is there a native method that does this already?

No, most native utility methods try not to mutate the array and instead return a new one.

> Is my solution unsound in some way?

Using `splice` and `unshift` repeatedly like you do is very inefficient. Better write

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.cherrypick == "function")
  console.warn("something already defines Array#cherrypick!");
Array.prototype.cherrypick = function(predicate) {
  let removed = [];
  for (let i=0, j=0; i<this.length; i++) {
    const item = this[i];
    if (fn(item)) {
      removed.push(item);
    } else {
      this[j++] = item; // keep in array, but at new position
    }
  }
  this.length = j; // removes rest
  return removed;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter twice:

```
const picked = array.filter(fn);
array = array.filter((el, i, a) => !fn(el, i, a));
```

Comment: I think he was hoping for something that wouldn't have to run all the tests twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce as follows :

```
  array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  fn = n => n % 3 == 0;
  [array, picked] = array.reduce ( (r, el) => (r[+fn(el)].push (el), r), [[], []] )
```

Comment: Exactly what @OriDori posted 10min ago?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
const basket = ['apple', 'banana', 'car'];
const filterMapBasket = basket
                       .filter(item => item !== 'car')
                       .map(item => {return { name: item }});
```

This will result the initial basket array of strings to be filtered and transformed to an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will alter the source array in place removing items meeting some test, and return those items...

```js
Array.prototype.removeIf = function(fn) {
    let i = this.length;
    let removed = [];
    while (i--) {
        if (fn(this[i], i)) {
            removed.push(...this.splice(i, 1));
        }
    }
    return removed;
};

let a = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let removed = a.removeIf(i => i%2);
console.log(a);
console.log(removed);
```